# Comparison of 2 cells with same value in VBA returns wrong output

Tags: excel, vba, compare, cells

So I have this code which lists through all sheets and compare cells in the 2nd row with cells in the 11th row. If they do not match it changes their color to red:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

 'Loop through each sheet and table in the workbook
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

  For i = 1 To 1000
    If sht.Cells(1, i) <> vbNullString Then
        If sht.Cells(2, i).Value = sht.Cells(11, i).Value Then
            sht.Cells(2, i).Interior.Color = xlNone
            sht.Cells(11, i).Interior.Color = xlNone
        Else
            sht.Cells(2, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            sht.Cells(11, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        End If
    Else
        Exit For
    End If

 Next i
```

However in one tab it colors some matching cells as well. The data I am comparing is an exported csv. If i manually rewrite the value of the compared cell and run the code the result is correct. The formating of cells is general in both rows. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try possibly `Trim(sht.Cells(2, i).Value) = Trim(sht.Cells(11, i).Value)`? If the values are *truly* the same, your procedure shouldn't color them. Often leading/trailing spaces will cause a discrepancy, as `0 ` != `0`, etc.

Comment: Awesome David, this worked. Probably some spaces slipped in at export/import. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you're not concerned about upper/lowercase (i.e., you consider "a" == "A"), then you should wrap each in the `LCase` function as well. Otherwise, it will highlight cells with same *value* but different case.